# Vercel site dont receive cookies from api on Render

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, cookies, mern

I build a MERN app that has an api on Render that works perfect on postman requests , but when i try to do the same requests with my Site on Vercel it doesnt receive the expected cookies from login .

I I tried everything I knew and searched for several answers to the problem, but unfortunately, I couldn't find anything that would solve my issue. All the requests work in Postman and the development environment.

Server.js :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GrnQG.png)

jwt.js :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GcnET.png)

and the frontend (newRequest.js) :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WD9m.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have identified the issue in the login function of the auth controllers. It turns out that I forgot to set the "sameSite" attribute to "none" in the login function. After making this adjustment, everything is now functioning correctly. Here is a screenshot for reference: